# remove or destroy child completely

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I've got a child named "viseur" that appears on a particular scene and replace my actual cursor.

When the event "removeViseur" is called, I would like to completely remove the child "viseur" (and I'll use my previous cursor).

I did that :

```
stage.addEventListener("functionCalled", removeViseur, false, 0, true);


public function removeViseur(e:Event):void{
                    trace("removeViseur");
                    viseur.visible = false;
            viseur.parent.removeChild(viseur);
                    viseur = null;
        }
```

The child "viseur" is no longer here, but if do Alt+tab or changing window and came back, the child "viseur" come back...

Do you know how I can destroy it completely ? (I don't need it after this function is called)

Thx,

### EDIT

Here is more of my code.

```
public static var viseur:Viseur;

var lookCocoDessous:Boolean = thisBack == "cocotierDessous";
if (lookCocoDessous) {
     viseur = new Viseur(stage);
    stage.addChild(viseur);
    viseur.visible = true;
stage.addEventListener("functionCalled", removeViseur, false, 0, true);

 public function removeViseur(e:Event):void{
                        trace("removeViseur");
                        viseur.visible = false;
                viseur.parent.removeChild(viseur);
                        viseur = null;
            }
```

And "viseur" has is own class like that

viseur.as :

```
public class Viseur extends MovieClip
    {
 private var engine:Engine;
        private var stageRef:Stage;
        private var p:Point = new Point(); 

        public function Viseur(stageRef:Stage)
        {

            Mouse.hide(); //make the mouse disappear
            mouseEnabled = false; //don't let our cursor block anything
mouseChildren = false;

            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            x = stageRef.mouseX;
            y = stageRef.mouseY;

            stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateMouse, false, 0, true);
            stageRef.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler, false, 0, true);
            stageRef.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, updateStack, false, 0, true);


        }

        private function updateStack(e:Event) : void
        {
            stageRef.addChild(this);
        }


        private function mouseLeaveHandler(e:Event) : void
        {
            visible = false;
            Mouse.show(); //in case of right click
            stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseReturnHandler, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function mouseReturnHandler(e:Event) : void
        {
            visible = true;
            Mouse.hide(); //in case of right click
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseReturnHandler);
        }

        private function updateMouse(e:MouseEvent) : void
        {
            x = stageRef.mouseX;
            y = stageRef.mouseY;

            e.updateAfterEvent();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Insufficient code to tell.  `viseur` is obviously a global variable, and just removing from the stage doesn't remove it from memory.  I'd suspect you have an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener which is running `addChild` at the specific coordinates of your cursor.  you can try `delete(viseur)` http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#delete, but you'd also have to encapsulate your cursor update code with `if (this.hasOwnProperty("viseur") {` to ensure you don't get "Unable to reference `null` object" errors.

Comment: try to remove all event listeners attached to stageRef in Viseur while deleting. probably  e.updateAfterEvent() adds object after deletion, because it is still somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Viseur` is adding itself to the stage whenever `Event.ADDED` fires.  This fires whenever anything is added to the stage (not just `Viseur`).  You've also made `Viseur` a static property, thus ensuring it doesn't disappear from memory.

To be succinct: add `Viseur` only once, and from outside of itself (thereby removing the need to pass a stage reference).  Be aware that once a DisplayObject is parented, it automatically gains `stage` & `root` properties which you can reference for mouseX and mouseY.

That said, if you're trying to replace the mouse cursor, I highly recommend taking a different tact: **Native** cursors.

See http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2012/07/as3-quickie-native-mouse-cursors/